# Frontend update of a development powerpoint add-in that is managed by the office admin center

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I have developed a powerpoint add-in and it is managed through the office admin center. The add-in is distributed to all members of our organisation.
It is deployed as a static website (in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)) that calls an API that is also deployed on GCP. The backend is deployed as a docker container in cloud run. The frontend is deployed as a static website in Cloud Storage.

The Add-In is distributed through the link to the manifest.xml which is stored at GCP. I want to update an API call of my backend that comes from the frontend. I want to send another variable in the json body.

The issue is that when I adapt my frontend and backend in the cloud the backend changes are immediately adapted since another container is called but the changes in my frontend are not updated. So the calls fail. Changes in the static website are not updated automatically. Probably office downloads the static website and stores it. But I somehow need to be able to update the frontend, right? Is there a way to trigger that the add in loads the files from the cloud again?

I already tried to clear the web cache and change the manifest.xml in the cloud.

This question is a duplicate of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1139068/frontend-update-of-a-develoyed-powerpoint-add-in-t.html since I did not get an answer there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook add-ins can take up to 24 hours to appear on app. See [Deploy add-ins in the Microsoft 365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide) for more information on that.

Also you may pay attention to the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers that holds directives (instructions) that control caching in browsers. So, you could set up internet headers on the files stored on the server to let browsers know how frequent they should be requested from the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The issue is not that it does not appear in the admin center but that frontend updates are not recognized. If I change something in the API calls from the frontend to the backend it is not updated in the admin managed version.
I already added this line to the index.html:
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"> 
It should therefore not be stored in cache, but it seems like it still is. Any ideas?

Comment: And the problem also remains if I clear the web cache. Also then updates an updated version is not available.